# How often Doctype, Metas, jquery in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, meta-tags, doctype

maybe a simple question, but cant find it in a trice.
i have an index.html with navigation and an iframe underneath, where other htmls are included by clicking on the navigation. in this other htmls i want to use the same jquery-, meta-, font-, etc-stuff like in the index.html. do i need to append the whole tags in the head of the included htmls or not? or is it enough to have it in the index.html?

thanks for help

Comment: I'd recommend against that design. The use of frames keeps the navigation on screen all the time (so people can't scroll it away to put more of the stuff they care about on screen) and people can't link/bookmark a document directly without jumping through hoops and then not having the navigation on the page they link to.

Comment: for what you ask, it looks like you need to learn php

Comment: thanks. this website ll be very tiny, less content. the navbar will also be fixed. but i admit: for "bigger" websites this design shouldn t be prefered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i need to append the whole tags in the head of the included htmls or not?

Yes. They are independent documents, they need to be complete documents.